# I want to display lines that contain a single bracket either its opening or closing

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Like I am having a  data like

```
1 -> (abc
 2-> abc)
```

one having opening parenthesis and 2 having closing parenthesis.

I am expecting like I have txt file I have both mistakes while entering  and missing want to echo all the occurrence of opening but absence of closing while another one is if only closing present. I am using bash code but it only shows for   occurrence of opening but absence of closing parenthesis my code is `grep -E '^[^()]*\([^()]*$|^[^()]*[^()]*\([^()]*$'` and this shows only result for `( abc`
but not for `abc)`. please help me out Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this regex is what you are looking for

```
grep -E '^[^()]*[()]{1}[^()]*$'
```

Comment: ok it works . but if there are more  of occurrence like a,b,c,(d,e,(f,g,h),k,l),m,n,(0 is there any solution for that?

Comment: In that case, you probably need a stack

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is highly optimized, so not exactly *programmable*. I used `sed`.

```
$: cat file
 foo
 1 -> (abc
 bar
 baz
 2-> abc)
 a,b,c,(d,e,(f,g,h),k,l),m,n,(0
 qux
 ( ( ( ( ) ) ( ) ( ( ) ) ) ) ( ( ) ( ) -> ) (
```

This worked pretty well using GNU `sed`:

```
$: sed -n 'h; :x; s/([^()]*)//; tx; /[()]/{=;x;p}' file | paste -d: - -
2: 1 -> (abc
5: 2-> abc)
6: a,b,c,(d,e,(f,g,h),k,l),m,n,(0
8: ( ( ( ( ) ) ( ) ( ( ) ) ) ) ( ( ) ( ) -> ) (
```

Broken out -
`-n` says `n`o printing unless explicitly requested.
`h`  says `h`old the original line of text in the hold buffer for reporting later.
`:x` declares a `label` for looping back to, see below.
`s/([^()]*)//` eliminates the innermost *matching pair* of parens.
`tx` loops back to the `x` label *if a substitution was made*.
`/[()]/{...}` scans the line to see if there are still any parens on it...
`=` report the line number.
`x` will e`x`change the edited line for the `h`eld original, so that
`p` can `p`rint it since it had unmatched parens.

I piped it through `paste -d: - -` to put the line numbers and lines on the same line of output.

I *think* the only GNU-specific feature there is using semicolons instead of newlines, so it should be pretty easy to adapt if needed.